# R: package installation trouble in Ubuntu

Tags: r, ubuntu, install.packages

I'm running on Ubuntu 16.04 (on a Lenovo ThinkPak T450). I have installed R version 3.4.1, installed by following the instructions [here](https://www.r-bloggers.com/how-to-install-r-ubuntu-16-04-xenial/) via Rbloggers.

From here, I would like to start installing packages, but if I run R from the command line *without root privileges*, I cannot access a CRAN mirror. That is, when I run `install.packages('dplyr')` (or any `install.packages('blah')`) I get the following error

```
--- Please select a CRAN mirror for use in this session ---
Error: .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'tcltk', details:
  call: fun(libname, pkgname)
  error: Can't find a usable init.tcl in the following directories: 
    /opt/anaconda1anaconda2anaconda3/lib/tcl8.5 ./lib/tcl8.5 ./lib/tcl8.5 ./library ./library ./tcl8.5.18/library ./tcl8.5.18/library
```

With that error, no CRAN mirror dialog box appears and hence no installation of packages. Note: this error does not happen when I start R with root privileges (i.e., start via `> sudo R`), but I do not want to install packages as root.

Thanks in advance for any help you can send my way!

**Edit**: Specifying the repo also results in error (in the file paths below, I replaced my user-name with `user-name`).

E.g.: `install.packages('Rcpp',repos='http://cran.us.r-project.org')` terminates with:

```
installing to /home/user-name/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/Rcpp/libs
** R
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** installing vignettes
** testing if installed package can be loaded
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘Rcpp’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
 unable to load shared object '/home/user-name/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/Rcpp/libs/Rcpp.so':
  /home/user-name/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/Rcpp/libs/Rcpp.so: undefined symbol: _ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEED1Ev
Error: loading failed
Execution halted
ERROR: loading failed
* removing ‘/home/user-name/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/Rcpp’
```

E.g., `install.packages('dplyr',repos='http://cran.us.r-project.org')` terminates with:

```
installing to /home/user-name/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/dplyr/libs
** R
** data
*** moving datasets to lazyload DB
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) : 
  unable to load shared object '/home/user-name/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/bindrcpp/libs/bindrcpp.so':
  /home/user-name/anaconda3/lib/R/bin/exec/../../lib/../.././libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by /home/user-name/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/bindrcpp/libs/bindrcpp.so)
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package ‘dplyr’
* removing ‘/home/user-name/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/dplyr’
```

Comment: As I said many times before, mix Anaconda and R at your own risk.  *Obviously* both the distro-native R package and the CRAN-hosted ported current package work. As does Rcpp.  I happen to both have a hand in those, and use them on multiple Ubuntu machines daily.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Thanks for you comment. By "mix", you mean have them both installed on the same system? Is there a good way to "un-mix" them; something such as removing the path to the Anaconda R directory from `.libPaths`? Forgive my ignorance here.

Comment: I would think so.  Start by splitting `$PATH`, possibly also `ld.so`.  Worst case, uninstall Conda?  I always got everything I needed for Python from Ubuntu plus occassional PyPI installations.  But then I am much heavier on R use so YMMV ...   Docker is good to split things off.

Comment: Great! Thanks @DirkEddelbuettel. I'll supply a solution below for the record, but the 'un-mixing' of R and Anaconda fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by DirkEddelbuettel in the comments, the issue was a mixing of Anaconda and R. To fix this problem:

- I uninstalled the R packages from Anaconda by first looking at `> conda list` and realizing that the package was `r-base`; hence running `> conda remove r-base`.
- Next, by looking at the output of `> which R`, it was clear that we were still trying to execute from the `../anaconda3/bin/..` directory. I suspect there is a quick way to change this via an export or bashrc amendment (or something similar), but for me, the quickest work-around was to run `> sudo apt-get install r-base r-base-dev`, which took all of 0.2 seconds as they were already installed, but it did affect the directory which the system looks in to the appropriate one, for me this is `/usr/bin/R/`.

From here I've been able to install everything I've needed.

Note: Thinking back, I suspect the "mixing" happened when I installed rpy2 via conda.